# Pulling instead pushing data from database

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, data-warehouse

Loading data from my OLTP database (it's part of ETL) via OPENQUERY or SSIS Data Flow to another SQL Server database (Warehouse which run this SSIS package / OPENQUERY statement), kills it. As I checked in Performance Monitor I use resources from source database, not from destiny. Is possible to reverse this resource utilization (using SQL Server 2016 or SSIS)?

Comment: What does 'kills it' mean? Can you explain the issue in technical terms? If you're transferring data from one system to another you'll need to use resources on both.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is in your destination write operation. If you are using OLE DB Destination with fast load access mode try setting the rows per batch value to a non-zero value and reduce the maximum insert commit size to a value that will be easy on your memory and CPU. SSIS will not have to wait for the default of 2147483647 before writing to the destination table which can have a large impact on your log file slowing your process down.  Please refer to this [Article](http://blog.exsilio.com/all/sql-server-integration-services-fast-load-so-fast-and-so-clean/) for more info on setting this values. All the best

[image]

Comment: I don't have problem with destination server (warehouse with SSIS instance) performance, but with source server (OLTP). I am looking for a method to decreasing resource usage in favor of the destination server.

Answer (score 0):

How does your export query looks like? Is it just a simple data dump or do you have some complex logic in (e.g. doing some denormalization/aggregation with the export)?

If it's just a simple export, check on which server your SSIS package runs and what resources it uses. In any case, you need to read the data from your source system, so expect some read disc operations.

In general it is better to get the data from an OLTP as quickly as possible and then apply other operations in further steps of your ETL process on your ETL/Data warehouse server. In order to reduce an impact on your transactional system.

Hope it helps.